# Como agrandar una imagen haciendole click y devolverla a su tamaño original con javascript

Tags: javascript, imagen, click

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

```
 var thumbnailElement = document.getElementById("smart_thumbnail");
thumbnailElement.addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert("I saw you click!");

    thumbnailElement.className = "";
    thumb.classList.remove("className");

    if (thumbnailElement.className == "")

        thumbnailElement.classList.contains("big")){
        thumbnailElement.classList.remove("big")
    }
    else {
        thumbnailElement.classList.add("big")
    }
});
```

});

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Tengo este codigo pero no funciona**

Comment: Edita tu pregunta e inserta el código en texto, es imposible que alguien te ayude y al mismo tiempo se ponga a reescribir tu código en texto.

Comment: el código va como texto, por favor [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/475389/edit) tu pregunta

Comment: Es más fácil y rápido pegar el código como texto que hacer una captura de pantalla y poner una imagen. Y por supuesto infinitamente más efectivo para conseguir una respuesta.

Comment: ya la editecomo texto

Answer (score 1):

Estás complicando la lógica de tu script:

```
// Con esta línea eliminas cualquier clase que tenga el elemento
thumbnailElement.className = "";
// Esta no tiene sentido, porque no tiene clases
thumb.classList.remove("className");

// Esto siempre será verdadero, porque eliminaste clases
if(thumbnailElement.className == "")
```

Para corregir tu código original solo necesitarías:

```
// Analizar si el elemento ya tiene la clase
if (thumbnailElement.classList.contains("big")) {
    // Sí la tiene, hay que eliminarla
    thumbnailElement.classList.remove("big");
} else {
    // No la tiene, hay que agregarla
    thumbnailElement.classList.add("big");
}
```

Sin embargo, hay una solución mucho más simple, con el método [.toggle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#m%C3%A9todos) que hará ese trabajo con una sola línea, sin comparaciones:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    let thumbnailElement = document.getElementById("smart_thumbnail");
    thumbnailElement.addEventListener("click", function() {
        // alert("I saw you click!");
        thumbnailElement.classList.toggle('big');
    });
});
```

```css
#smart_thumbnail { width: 200px; }
#smart_thumbnail.big { width:400px;; }
```

```html
<img id="smart_thumbnail" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBG3I.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo cree un codigo asi en uno de mis practicas personales al hacer paginas webs.
Para ese casi, yo utilice este codigo.

Espero te sirva.

```
function showImage(e) {
    const id = parseInt( e.target.dataset.imageId ); //Este codigo de aqui fue usado para crear una galeria antes.

    //Generar la imagen
    const image = document.createElement('IMG');
    image.src = `src/img-grande/${id}.webp`;

    const overlay = document.createElement('DIV');
    overlay.appendChild(image);
    overlay.classList.add('overlay');
    //Se cierra cuando das click en cualquier parte de la pantalla
    overlay.onclick = function() {
        overlay.remove();
        body.classList.remove('class-body');

    };

    //Boton cerrar imagen
    const closeImage = document.createElement('P');
    closeImage.textContent = 'X';
    closeImage.classList.add('close-btn');

    //Boton cerrar imagen accion
    closeImage.onclick = function() {
        overlay.remove();
        body.classList.remove('class-body');
    };

    overlay.appendChild(closeImage);

    //Agrandado en el HTML
    const body = document.querySelector('body');
    body.appendChild(overlay);
    body.classList.add('class-body');

};
```

Puedo responder con el link de la pagina que cree si deseas.